# Вывод двух графиков в chart C#

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Пытаюсь вывести два графика(series[0]-гистограмма, series[1]- график) и постоянно получаю такое "Проиндексированные ряды (XValueIndexed = true) невозможно отобразить на одной и той же оси, если они не выровнены.Ряды "Series1" и "Series2" должны быть выровнены для выполнения данной операции. В настоящий момент эти ряды содержат разное количество точек данных".

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(ListOfDiapazonsMiddle[i], ListOfChastot[i] / ListOfLengthDiapazons[i]);
chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindY(yExponencialn[i]);
```

У графиков по оси X будет разное кол-во точек, то есть гистограмма(series[0]) 10-17 точек, график(series[1]) 100-500 точек. При этом точки графика series[1] строятся по оси Y, а по X просто диапазон по кол-ву точек. Соответственно вопрос, можно ли вывести это на одном графике?

Comment: Не все типы графиков совместимы, проверьте что ваши являются совместимыми (на вскидку не помню, могу посмотреть позже). Для совмещения некоторых типов графиков количество точек должно быть одинаковым, недостающие точки можно получить, например, интерполяцией или подстановкой пустых точек.

Comment: Сделал на двух разных графиках, как на одном отобразить так и не разобрался.

Comment: приведите набор данных, на котором проявляется ошибка. Достаточно десятка точек для каждой серии, если наборы разной длины, в примере тоже дол отличаться хотя-бы на одну точку. Желаемые типы графиков. И, если не сложно, ожидаемое отображение, можно тупо в paint сделать, не обязательно скрин

Comment: более подробно опишу вопрос. Пока выполнял работу, понял что немного подругому надо делать. У графиков по оси X будут разные кол-ва точек, то есть гистограмма(series[0]) 10-17 точек, график(series[1]) 100 - 500 точек. При этом все точки из одного list'a, только график по всем точкам, а гистограмма по определенным. Соответственно вопрос, можно ли вывести это на одном графике?

Comment: [Поправьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/745202/edit) описание в вопросе. Попробую, позже отпишусь, но есть вероятность, что нельзя. Точки из разных наборов имеют хоть какое-то соотношение между собой? На крайний случай, можно на одном Chart-контроле отобразить 2 графика, но в разных областях, т.е. фактически рисоваться два графика, но не наложением, а рядом, или один под другим

Comment: Я так и сделал, вывел каждый график на свой chart. Но в идеале лучше наложением выводить, чтоб нагляднее было) Точки у графика(series[1]) свои, по формуле вычисляются и выводятся. Скорее всего на одной оси X никак не вывести, сам масштаб разный, график ~500 т., а гистограмма ~17т. и значения от 0 до 2(это важно). Я хотел узнать может способ есть на одном charte 2 оси X отобразить и вторую скрыть.

Comment: ну тогда вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос. Chart на позволяет отображать на одной области несовместимые по масштабу графики. Там еще есть особенности, например нельзя совмещать круговые диаграммы с гистограммами, полярные совместимы только с полярными и т.д.